# Given only dimensions for N vectors, is it possible to construct a polytope?

Tags: polytopes

We are given a set of magnitude of vectors. These vectors are free to move and rotate in space. How can we verify that whether this set of given vectors form a [polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope)?

Comment: Do you really mean the whole polytope?  Or could you mean the vertices of a convex polytope? In the latter case, such a polytope always exists, for any finite set of lengths.

Comment: Do you mean whether a finite list of positive real numbers are the edge-lengths of some 3-dimensional polytope?